# Password button and userform

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have programmed the following userform in Excel VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Password = TextBox1.Text
If Password = a Then
MsgBox "Password Correct.", vbInformation
Unload Me
Else
MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

The password variable a = "test"

This password userform itself works perfectly. Now I want to connect it to a button that is already in the sheet. The code behind this button is in the section "ThisWorkbook" in the VBA editor:

```
Sub Button_Test()
UserForm1.Show
Tabelle2.Range("C3").Value = 1
End Sub
```

The idea is that the button "Button_Test" is protected by a password that can be entered by the userform. Once the password is correctly entered the macro "Tabelle2.Range("C3").Value = 1" will be conducted.

However, currently I have the issue that the userform responses me with "Password Correct" but does not start the macro "Tabelle2.Range("C3").Value = 1".

How can I tell the userform once the password is entered correct it should jump back to the macro "Button_Test" and continue the procedure?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is exactly what should happen with the code you posted. Does the userform unload?

Comment: I guess you need to call `Unload Me` in the click handler of your button to close the form.

Comment: I restarted the file and now it works. Not sure why. However, when the userform appears and I click on the sign "X" on the right top of the userform the macro starts altough I did not enter a password. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can use the `Userform_QueryClose` event to cancel if they click the X: `If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True`. Personally I'd redesign to add a Valid property to the form that you can check from the calling code before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work with a boolean value that you will set on true when the Password was correct. You Could make something like this:

**Code in Modul or Sheet**

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
'Load funktion Check Password
If UserForm1.checkPassword() = True Then
    'Run this Code when PWD was Correct
    Tabelle1.Range("C3").Value = 1
End If
End Sub
```

**And in the UserForm you can Put a Code Like that:**

```
Private passwordStatus As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String
    Dim Password As String

    a = "123"
    Password = TextBox1.Text
    'Set Pawwordstatus at False before Testing
    passwordStatus = False
    If Password = a Then
        MsgBox "Password Correct.", vbInformation
        passwordStatus = True
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Function checkPassword() As Boolean
  UserForm1.Show
  'Shows the User Form. And after Closing the Form
  'The PasswordStatus Value will be returned and you can check if
  'it is true
  checkPassword = passwordStatus
End Function
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for this great idea.