# Continue procedure if CommandButton is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

So far I have used the below `VBA` in order to continue with a procedure if the user clicked `ok` in the `MsgBox`:

```
Sub Button_Message_Box()
Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue the procedure?", vbOK)
    If Answer = vbOK Then
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Now I want to achieve the exact same result using `CommandButton1` in `UserForm1`. 
Therefore I tried to go with this:

**(1)** VBA in `UserForm1`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

**(2)** VBA in `Modul1`:

```
Sub Button_Procedure()
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
If CommandButton1 = True Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

The `VBA` goes through but it does not enter the value `1` into `Cell A1`. 
What do I need to modify to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why not attach the code to the click event?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with: `If CommandButton1 = True Then`? You are opening the form in `Modeless` mode; that if condition will be meet long time before you press any buttons on the form (which is where i'm presuming the value for **CommandButton1** comes from?). In which case **CommandButton1** will never be true at that stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805593/password-button-and-userform) question I used a Boolean variable:

**(1)** Code in `UserForm1`:

```
Private continue_procedure As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
continue_procedure = True
Unload Me
End Sub

Function check_procedure() As Boolean
UserForm1.Show
check_procedure = continue_procedure
End Function
```

**(2)** Code in `Modul1`:

```
Sub Button_Procedure()
If UserForm1.check_procedure() = True Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to follow the steps in this article: [Rubberduck: UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Nevertheless, a simple and dirty implementation could be as follows:

**The form's code behind:**

Add an event to raise when the OK-Cancel button has been pressed passing a boolean value indicating either to proceed or not:

```
Public Event OnClose(ByVal bool As Boolean)

Private Sub CmdOK_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnClose(True)
End Sub

Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnClose(False)
End Sub
```

**A simple wrapper class:**

Here, we just instantiate the form and listen to the `OnClose()` event.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objForm As UserForm1
Private m_flag As Boolean

Public Function Show() As Boolean
    Set objForm = New UserForm1
    objForm.Show ' No vbModeless here, we want to halt code execution
    Show = m_flag
End Function

Private Sub CloseForm()
    Unload objForm
    Set objForm = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objForm_OnClose(ByVal bool As Boolean)
    m_flag = bool
    CloseForm
End Sub
```

**Calling the wrapper class:**

```
Sub Something()

    Dim bool As Boolean

    With New FormWrapper
        bool = .Show
    End With

    MsgBox "Should I proceed? " & bool
End Sub
```