# Change value of public variable if checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I created a `UserForm1` and inserted a `CheckBox1`.

Now, if the user checks the `CheckBox1` I want that the `public variable` called `CheckBox1_Value` gets asigned the value `1` to it. 
 If the `Checkbox1` is not checked the variable should get asigned the value `0` to it.

Afterwards I want to run a second `VBA` which inserts the value of this variable into `Sheet1.Range("A1")`.

---

I tried to do this with the following codes:

**1) UserForm1:**

```
Public CheckBox1_Value

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Filter_Data.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1_Value = 1
    Else
    CheckBox1_Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

**2) Module**

```
Sub Value_of_variable ()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = CheckBox1_Value
End Sub
```

---

The codes above are running without any error message but the value of the `public variable` is not entered into `Sheet1.Range("A1")`. The cell remains emtpy so I assume somehow the value is not assigned/extracted correctly to/from the `variable`.

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: You do not explain where/when you are calling `Value_of_variable`

Comment: Also, to toggle a `Boolean` you can just do something like... `CheckBox1.Value = Not CheckBox1.Value` - no need for an entire `If` statement.

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` in every module.

Comment: @braX: Thanks for the hint with the boolean variable. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in one of the comments the best solution for this is using a `Boolean variable` referring to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639852/continue-procedure-if-commandbutton-is-clicked):

**1) UserForm1 (Filter_Data):**

```
Private continue_procedure As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Filter_Data.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    continue_procedure = True
    Else
    continue_procedure = False
    End If
Unload Me
End Sub

Function check_procedure() As Boolean
Filter_Data.Show
check_procedure = continue_procedure
End Function
```

**2) Module**

```
Sub Value_of_variable()
If Filter_Data.check_procedure() = True Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```

Of course this only works if there is only a True/False option for the variable but in this case that is what should be achieved with the `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle a `Boolean` you can just do something like...

```
CheckBox1.Value = Not CheckBox1.Value
```

There is no need for an entire `If` statement if that's the only thing you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Value_of_variable` is not automatically run when `CheckBox1_Click()` executes.

Simplists solution would be to link the Checkbox Data Source to that cell.

Alternatively, add a call to `Value_of_variable` into `CheckBox1_Click()`

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   CheckBox1_Value = SubFilter_Data.CheckBox1.Value
   Value_of_variable
End Sub
```

And change `Value_of_variable` to

```
Sub Value_of_variable ()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.CheckBox1_Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Public variable defined in class module still won't be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan looks a little convoluted. Without knowing your final intention, please try the direct most approach first. In your user form's code sheet add this procedure.

```
Option Explicit
' 003

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Sheet1.Cells(1, "A").Value = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

**Notes**

1. You specify `Sheet1` which isn't necessarily the same as `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. If you are mentioning the name you (or Excel) gave to tab, the latter is the correct way.
2. The code will write either TRUE or FALSE to the cell. For Excel's purposes that is faster than 0 and 1 (which would probably have to be converted back to True and False), but if you really want 0 and 1 then change the code in the procedure to

`Sheet1.Cells(1, "A").Value = IIf(CheckBox1.Value, 1, 0)`

I'm not offering a solution in which the value is assigned to a publish variable because it looks unlikely that you need such a tool if the value is already in the sheet, from where you can process it in whichever way you prefer. Logically, if you want a publish variable, writing it to the sheet shouldn't be required.

Answer (score -1):

Move the `Public` variable from inside UserForm code pane to any normal Module code pane

So for instance in the code pane where your `Value_of_variable()` sub resides it would be something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public CheckBox1_Value

Sub Value_of_variable()

    With New Filter_Data ' make a new instance of your userform
        .Show ' show the userform
    End With ' terminate the Userform. Any changes made to the Public variable are safely stored in it

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = CheckBox1_Value ' write the Public variable in Sheet1

End Sub
```

And your `Filter_Data` userform code would correspondingly be:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        CheckBox1_Value = 1 ' change the Public variable
    Else
        CheckBox1_Value = 0 ' change the Public variable
    End If
End Sub
```